# Can't upload files in android webview application

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient, webchromeclient

I am using simple webview for my responsive website. App is working fine but the file upload control is not working, I can't upload images, docs, ppt or excel files from the app.

I have created webview in android studio.

I have added following code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://myurl.com/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);

final Activity activity = this;
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But it opens app in browser. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you declared your permissions right?

Comment: Maybe use webview postData method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl(java.lang.String, byte[])

Comment: Its not working @nurisezgin but thanks for your reply.

Comment: hey @Kristo1990 i have given all the permissions